# How can I manipulate the values on a form when the submit button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

**Update 2 - Solved**

On reflection with Update 1 I was close to solving my problem, this is my final solution.

```
<button type='submit' onclick="validate()" class='btn btn-default'>Submit</button>


validate = function() {
       document.getElementById('id_Price').value="2988.99"
}
```

**Update 1**

I have had a bit more success with this -

```
<button type='submit' onclick="validate()" class='btn btn-default'>Submit</button>


validate = function() {
  console.log("Anything happening? (2)")

  RoomBookingsForm['Price'].value()="2988.99"
  document.getElementById('id_Price').value()="2988.99"
}
```

**Original Question**

How can I manipaluate the values on a form when the submit button is clicked? I have tried -

```
<button type='submit' class='btn btn-default'>Submit</button>
function submit(){
  document.getElementById('id_Price').innerHTML()="2988.99"
  RoomBookingsForm['Price'].value()="2988.99"
  document.getElementById('id_Price').value()="2988.99"
}


<button type='submit' onsubmit='submitForm()' class='btn btn-default'>Submit</button>          
function submitForm(){
  document.getElementById('id_Price').innerHTML()="2988.99"
  RoomBookingsForm['Price'].value()="2988.99"
  document.getElementById('id_Price').value()="2988.99"
}
```

The purpose of this is to present the dates on the form based on the users language / timezone web browser settings. But ultimately save the date to the backend using the American format.

Comment: What sort of input is `id_Price` as you've attempted both `innerHTML` and `value` (both incorrectly, but it should be one or the other) ?

Comment: Check the browser console (F12, select console) to see any errors.  Essentially, you can't do `function() = something` - it would either be `object.property = something` or `object.function(something)`.

Comment: Does this help? - <input type="number" name="Price" value="39.99" step="0.01" class="numberinput form-control" required="" id="id_Price">

Comment: not sure where you learned how to set a form value that way, but it is wrong.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609130/set-the-value-of-an-input-field

Comment: buttons do not have submit events, forms do.

Comment: epascarello my problem is setting a form value once the form has been submitted

Comment: This was one of my reference points - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44989121/run-javascript-function-on-form-submit

Comment: I can't make heads or tails of this question because of all the Update headers. Please [edit] your question so that there is one cohesive question, as if you are asking the question from the start, knowing what you know from the updates.

Comment: Apologies. I have solved my problem and need no more help. I added Update 2 in case anyone else faces my issue in the future.

Comment: Answers should be in answers, not in questions.

Comment: A. Meshu did that for me just now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to change the value when user hits `submit` you can (for example) change the `type` to `button` and then submit your data programaticaly via `js`.

Something like this:

```js
validate = function() {
  // change value when click
  document.getElementById('id_Price').value="2988.99";
  // submit the form progrematically 
  document.getElementById('demo').submit();
}
```

```html
<form id="demo">
  <input id="id_Price" value="100" />
  <button type='button' onclick="validate()" class='btn btn-default'>Submit</button>
</form>
```